# if touching object move to location aframe

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am wondering how it would be possible in aframe if the  camera reaches 20 spaces away from the point 0 0 0 to teleport them back to that point. Would something like this be easy to achieve or difficult? How can I achieve this.

Comment: *javascript* to the rescue - [get the position](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/entity.html#getattribute-componentname), [calculate the distance to `0 0 0`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.distanceTo) and if bigger than 20 [set the new position](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/position.html#updating-position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the position of the object using `el.object3D.position` - that would return x,y,z vector or you can use `el.object3D.position.x` (or .y / .z for just one axis).

You can also set the position using the same function `el.object3D.position.x = 23.12`.

As @Piotr Adam Milewski said, you would need to calculate the distance - you could use the following expression `distance = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)` or use the `THREE.Vector3.distanceTo()` then compare it to some value and set the position accordingly (camera default position is `0, 1.6, 0` and not `0, 0, 0`).

#### A very simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('limit-my-distance', {
      init: function() {
        this.zero = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
      },
      tick: function() {
        if (this.el.object3D.position.distanceTo(this.zero) > 10) {
          this.el.object3D.position.set(0, 1.6, 0);
        }
        //this.el.object3D.position.x += 0.1;
      }
    });
  </script>
  <a-scene>
    <a-sphere position="0 2 -10"color="red"></a-sphere>
    <a-plane color="green" position="0 0 -5" rotation="-90 0 0" width="20" height="20"></a-plane>
    <a-camera limit-my-distance></a-camera>
    <a-sky color="#fff"></a-sky>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The example below is working for the sphere but when I transfer to to the camera, it stops working and doesn't restrict my movement. Any ideas why?

Comment: do you have a glitch or fiddle?

Comment: I edited the example for the camera. It's hard to guess what went wrong for you. Can you share some code?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply but the code is working perfectly. The only thing is that its only when moving 10 spaces tp the right that you're moved back to the original position. How can I make it so its when the camera moves 10 spaces in any direction. Meaning the camera is at least 10 spaces away from the point 0 0 0 instead of just in the direction right. Also is it possible to remove the always moving aspect and let the player control the camera without messing up the code?